# VBA Excel Macro won't email out - error

Tags: vba, excel, email, cdo.message

I have the following code to test to email out to specified email addresses. At present it won't work.

It says "Label not defined".

```
    Sub GHF()

    Dim CDO_Mail As Object
    Dim CDO_Config As Object
    Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strFrom As String
    Dim strTo As String
    Dim strCc As String
    Dim strBcc As String
    Dim strBody As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Feedback")
    ws.Select

    strSubject = " Assessment Centre Feedback"
    strFrom = "test@email.com"
    strTo = Value & Range("M4").Value
    strCc = ""
    strBcc = ""
    strBody = "Dear" & Value & Range("M4").Value & "Thank you for attending assesssment Centre. Please find attached your feedback from the day. Kind Regards, Employer"

    Set CDO_Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    On Error GoTo Error_Handling

    Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    CDO_Config.Load -1

    Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields

    With SMTP_Config
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "fermat.axiomtech.co.uk"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item.Configuration.Fields.Update
    End With

    With CDO_Mail
        Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
    End With
    End Sub
```

The name of the spreadsheet where the data sits is called "Feedback" and the Workbook is called "Feedback with Email"

Can anyone help with identifying what's up?

Comment: You have an error handler advising to go to a label that doesn't exist...

Comment: Remove the `On Error GoTo Error_Handling` row. Or even better, write a proper error handling.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I've done this and there's no error code but I've not received the emails. I don't know why.

Comment: try `.Update` instead of `.Item.Configuration.Fields.Update`

Comment: Which office your running?

Comment: Hi all, I'm running Outlook 2013. I've managed to get it to work by replacing
`CDO_mail` with `Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail`. Next issue, is I can't work out how to specify the "from" address

Comment: See my answer, let me know

Comment: Any update?....

Answer (score 0):

From address & Password

```
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xyz@Email.com" 
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "123456"
```